# Linux Show a message to the connected display without logging

Tags: linux, user-interface, x11

Hello I am trying to secure a linux machine that I have built. 
I want to prevent people from clonning the hard disk drive. 
I have a script that runs with init on startup and every 1 hour.

Script is something like this. It has hard coded hard disk drive serial number, motherboard serial number and few other serials. Script checks the serial of number of the hard drive and mother against hard coded serial. If it does not match. It sends a halt message to the system and the system shuts down.

Now I want to display a message on the connected display / monitor before halting the system. Obviously user wont be logged on when this happens. So I am looking for a way to send the message to the screen without logging.

Here is the script snippet.

```
#!/bin/bash
$coded-hdserial="W4837486938473ASD534354"
$coded-mbserial="XFD6345-32423-IRJDFJDF-234823729"

$check-hdserial=`smartctl -i /dev/sda | grep "Serial Number" | awk -F ":" {'print $2'} |  sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'`
$check-mbserial=`lshw | grep -A 15 "*-core" | grep "serial:" | awk -F ":" {'print $2'} |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -d '.'`

if 
$coded-hdserial == $check-hdserial
then
echo "OK" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
echo "This copy of the software cannot be validated, it may be is a counterfeit. Therefore you cannot continue to enjoy the privilege to use this software. Please contact the support for further information. 

This system will now be shut down. Further attempts to make counterfeit or duplicate copies of this system will initiate the self destruction and you will loose all data."
halt in 1 minute
fi

if 
$coded-mbserial == $check-mbserial
then
echo "OK" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
echo "This copy of the software cannot be validated, it may be is a counterfeit. Therefore you cannot continue to enjoy the privilege to use this software. Please contact the support for further information. 

This system will now be shut down. Further attempts to make counterfeit or duplicate copies of this system will initiate the self destruction and you will loose all data."
halt in 1 minute
fi
```

My question how can I display a good nice looking warning message to connected monitor. Or probably a JPG image on the screen with warning.

Comment: So you don't want to use the `echo` command, and instead want something that is slightly prettier, like a modal dialog?

Comment: correct, is there a way to display an "JPG" image on the screen without GUI x-window or KDE installed?

Comment: Are you running your application from the suspicious hard disk which has been tampered with? Think twice about trusting your hard coded value for what the serials should be.

Comment: As an aside, your script contains a large number of syntax errors.  The dollar sign introduces variable interpolation; it should not be used on the name of a variable you are assigning to. (Strictly, if `foo` contains `bar`, then `$foo="baz"` assigns the value `"baz"` to the variable `bar`.)  Furthermore, variable names cannot contain hyphens.

Comment: Similarly, the argument to `if` is a command whose result code will be evaluated.  As your intent is clearly to compare the text of two variables, you probably mean `if [[ $codedmbserial = $checkhdserial ]]; then`...

Comment: And of course, `grep | awk | sed` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and in most cases a useless `sed`, too.  These can usually be refactored to a single Awk script, usually with a more legible and maintainable end result as well as more efficient code.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of security threat you are guarding against.

Answer (score 0):

Look at kernel support for frame buffer devices to which you might be able to dump raw pixel data like from a bitmap image file. This is how the GRand Unified Bootloader (GRUB) makes a graphical boot menu. No need for X, but you won't get actual dialog windows. If you want a lightweight ASCII art interactive menu system, look at a Curses implementations like ncurses.